# Facebook "signed_request" using pure Classic ASP

Tags: facebook, asp-classic, base64

I would like to get the contents of the `signed_request` in my fb app, but using only Classic ASP with VBScript.

Facebook's site has an example in PHP of decoding this but I can't find anything for ASP.

I think I need to decode the base64url, then read the JSON, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

I was in the same boat you are. All of the sites which provide code to create a gate are written in PHP. Using the code on ChiliPepperDesign's ["Reveal / Fan-Gate / Like-Gate Facebook iFrame Tab"](http://www.chilipepperdesign.com/2011/02/15/reveal-fan-gate-like-gate-facebook-iframe-tab-tutorial-with-php) as a starting point, I converted the PHP to ASP/VBScript, and found sources for the base64 decode and JSON decode (which PHP apparently does natively).

The JSON.decode script I got from [GitHub](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js). Yes, it is Javascript, but you can run it on an ASP/VBScript site if you preface the code on the page with this:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<script language="JSCRIPT" runat="server">
```

Put all of the downloaded Javascript in, and then close with the usual `</script>` tag. Save this file as **json_decode.asp**.

The base64 decode was a little harder (the one I initially downloaded sorta worked and sorta did NOT work). I found a better version on [Free VBCode](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5248). Downlaod that and put it into another file, **base64_encode-decode.asp**.

Finally, the code to bring it all together is:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>

<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="base64_encode-decode.asp" -->
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="json_decode.asp" -->

<%
Dim encoded_sig, payload, sig, data, myArray

Function parsePageSignedRequest()
    If Request("signed_request") <> "" THEN

        myArray = Split(Request("signed_request"), ".")
        encoded_sig = myArray(0)
        payload = myArray(1)

        sig = base64_decode(Replace(encoded_sig, "-_", "+/"))
        set data = JSON.parse(base64_decode(Replace(payload, "-_", "+/")))

        parsePageSignedRequest = data

        If data.page.liked Then %>
        <p>Thank you for liking us!</p>
        <% Else %>
        <p>Please click the "like" button to continue.</p>
        <% End If
    Else
        parsePageSignedRequest = ""
    End If
End Function

'' -- run the function
parsePageSignedRequest()
%>
```

Save this as **facebook-likeGate.asp** on your site in the same location as the two include files, and point Facebook to this page.

HTH

JF

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code without the use of json_decode.asp

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!-- #INCLUDE FILE="base64_encode-decode.asp" -->
<% 
Dim encoded_sig, payload, sig, data, myArray

Function parsePageSignedRequest()
    If Request("signed_request") <> "" THEN
        myArray = Split(Request("signed_request"), ".")
        payload     = myArray(1)
        payload = base64_decode(payload)

        If instr(payload,"liked"":true,") Then %>
        <p>Thank you for liking us!</p>
        <% Else %>
        <p>Please click the "like" button to continue.</p>
        <% End If
    Else
        parsePageSignedRequest = ""
    End If
End Function
parsePageSignedRequest()
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use new JS SDK. Here is a sample which I have coded and used. Post method works good.

```
<head> 
     <SCRIPT language="JavaScript"> 
  setInterval('SubMe()',1500);
function SubMe() 
{ 
  if(document.getElementById('fbmail').value != ''){ 

document.form.submit();

}

} 


</SCRIPT>

  </head> 

<body> 

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<h2></h2><br />
<div id="user-info"></div>
<p><fb:login-button scope="email,publish_stream,user_about_me,user_location,user_birthday" on-login="top.location = '';" autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button></p>


<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({ appId: 'APP ID', 
        status: true, 
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true});

  function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

    if (response.authResponse) {
      //user is already logged in and connected
      var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
      FB.api('/me', function(response) {
         userInfo.innerHTML='Redirecting...If doesnt work click <a href="">here</a>';
          document.getElementById('fbmail').value = response.email;
        document.getElementById('fbid').value = response.id;
         document.getElementById('fbname').value = response.name;
          document.getElementById('fbbirthday').value = response.birthday;
           document.getElementById('fbhometown').value = response.hometown.name;
        button.innerHTML = 'Logout';

      });
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.logout(function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
          userInfo.innerHTML="";
    });
      };
    } else {
      //user is not connected to your app or logged out
      button.innerHTML = 'Logout';
      button.onclick = function() {
        FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
          var userInfo = document.getElementById('user-info');
         userInfo.innerHTML='Redirecting...If doesnt work click <a href="">here</a>';
          document.getElementById('fbmail').value = response.email;
        document.getElementById('fbid').value = response.id;
         document.getElementById('fbname').value = response.name;
          document.getElementById('fbbirthday').value = response.birthday;
           document.getElementById('fbhometown').value = response.hometown.name;
        });    
          } else {
            //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
          }
        }, {scope:'email'});    
      }
    }
  }

  // run once with current status and whenever the status changes
  FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);    
};

(function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol 
    + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

</script>
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="go_little_caeser.asp">
<input name="fbmail" id="fbmail" type="hidden">

<input name="fbid" id="fbid" type="hidden">
<input name="fbname" id="fbname" type="hidden">
<input name="fbbirthday" id="fbbirthday" type="hidden">
<input name="fbhometown" id="fbhometown" type="hidden">
</form>
</body>
```